# Source code viewers to display parts of the same file side by side

Tags: visual-studio, language-agnostic, ide

Are there any tools or IDE features to allow viewing of different parts of the *same* file side-by-side.

I've often thought this would be useful for analysing and refactoring duplicated code within a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notepad++ -> view -> clone to another view

You can even synchronize scrolling of two different positions on same file.

Comment: Excellent, it's free. That'll do nicely!

Answer (score 3):

Any programmers editor should support this - vim certainly does.

Comment: Even my little tiny one. xacc.ide does that!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I've used Beyond Compare for years and it is the best that I have found.  Especially since you have the ability to do diffs as well as just look at the files.  This tool is also the best that I have found for doing binary comparisons.  Look at www.scootersoftware.com

Answer (score 0):

In VisualStudio: Window Menu, split?

Comment: I've tried that - it doesn't seem to let you display the same file in two panes though.

Answer (score 0):

notepad++ ...

its free and easy to use